# Magnetic Potential Energy

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

Does a charged rod or a shell have a magnetic potential energy when it is kept in a uniform magnetic field?

Also, can anyone quantitatively explain why a wire loop carrying current would tend to be circular?

Answer (score 6):

The [magnetic moment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force_between_magnets#Magnetic_dipole_moment) of a dipole (in this case, the loop) is given by
$$
\mu=I A
$$
where $I$ is the current carried by the wire, and $A$ its area.

The [potential energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_moment#Force_on_a_moment) of a dipole, when in presence of a magnetic field $B$ is
$$
W=-\mu B \cos\theta
$$
where $\theta$ is the angle between the direction normal to the wire and the direction of the magnetic field. In this case, we are taking $\theta=0$ (because the wire is perpendicular to the magnetic field), so $W=-IAB$.

With this, you can see that $W$ is minimised when $A$ is maximised.

Comment: So, does the area of the wire automatically increase? like,on its own? I thought only torques were produced...

Comment: 1) Yes: the loop gets stretched out into a circle. I've been trying to find a video on youtube, but with no luck, sorry 2) It's not just *on its own*: it's the effect of the magnetic force, which means the loop gets "pulled" by this force. 3) only torques are produced on **circular loops**. If the wire is not a loop, first it gets stretched out into a circle, and *then* it feels a torque. Hope this answers your question :)

Comment: If I prove this by Lorentz Force on the wire, would it be just?

Comment: yes, but I believe its easiest to prove using energy arguments (i.e., to prove that a circle maximeses area, and therefore mininises potential energy). If you manage to prove this using the Lorentz Force, post it here: I would like to see it! (though I fear its not easy to do so...)

Comment: I'm just talking about a qualitative proof @AccidentalFourierTransform

Comment: Like, one can easily see that there are forces acting on the wire loop which is irregularly shaped,and the components would not cancel due to irregularity,so every small length element dl will experience a force Bidl outwards or inwards, which would lead to formation of a circular shape and that will be the condition at which net force will be zero or the loop.

Comment: Oh, I see. Yes, that's a nice description! I thought you were after explicit equations, but if you put it that way then yes, the Lorentz Force works just fine :)

Comment: It would be tedious to integrate and find out by equations using Lorentz Force and also, you would have to have the shape or some initial conditions about the shape to start off with, yours is still a better explanation though, Thanks.

Comment: Actually, I didn't read that a current was flowing through the loop, so I couldn't think of any reason (being the dipole moment and torque here and -m.B as potential energy), I was thinking if a wire loop with no current,placed in a magnetic field, can have a magnetic potential energy?

Comment: @Quark no, if the wire carries no current then it won't be affected by a constant magnetic field.